# Adding a sum column

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have 11 total Columns and I need to add a 12th column that is a sum of columns 2-11.
I really don’t know how to do it and can use any help thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have two steps:

1. summing up each row
2. concatenating it to the 12th column

Let's say your matrix is `mat`

1. `x = sum(mat, 2)` will sum all the columns.
2. `horzcat(mat, x)` will concatenate the sum a the last

I am sure you can adjust the following code to the way you want

> a = rand(2,4)

a =

```
0.8147    0.1270    0.6324    0.2785
0.9058    0.9134    0.0975    0.5469
```

> sum(a,2)

ans =

```
1.8526
2.4636
```

> horzcat( a, sum(a,2))

ans =

```
0.8147    0.1270    0.6324    0.2785    1.8526
0.9058    0.9134    0.0975    0.5469    2.4636
```